# How to copy certain line with specific word from a Richtextbox into another Richtextbox?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, richtextbox, keyword-search

I have a Richtextbox with many words in each line.

Here's the layout:

[image]

When I click the "FILTER DATA" button, let says Button2, I want it to copy sentences on certain line from Richtextbox1 on the left side to the Richtextbox2 on the right side, which contains specific keyword that I input in the Textbox1 at the middle top of the form.

For Example, when I type "1" in the KEYWORDS textbox, the button will copy sentences of line 1 and 10 into Richtextbox2.

Comment: You can use loop and also use .contains(tbKeywords.text)

Comment: It would be a *lot* easier if you used a ListBox or ListView for this, rather than a free-form TextBox/RichTextBox.

Comment: @user64322 Hi and thanks for spend your time for answering my questions.

Yes I've tried that .contains(tbKeywords.text) method and it works, but what I confused is how to copy the Richtextbox1 words to Richtextbox2 only the line that contains keyword which I input in the Textbox1.



   Richtextbox2.text = ?????

Comment: @CodyGray Hi and thanks for spend your time for answering my questions. Why I use a free-form Richtextbox because I want to import the text content from external file which in .txt format such as notepad.